# ThreadLocal и передача массива из нескольких потоков

Tags: java, массивы, многопоточность

Недавно начал изучать многопоточность в Java, добрался до полей типа ThreadLocal. В принципе с его работой разобрался, с переменными примитивных типов проблем нет, а вот при работе с массивами получается какая-то ерунда.

**Код примера**

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {

    private static final ThreadLocal<List> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private static final String AB = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private static SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
    private static List<String> array = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    threadLocal.set(returnSomeList(Thread.currentThread().getName()));
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + threadLocal.get());
                }
            });
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    public static List<String> returnSomeList(String name) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(16);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
            }
            array.add(name + " : " + sb.toString());
            sb = new StringBuilder(16);
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Есть метод **returnSomeList(String name)**, который возвращает массив двух строк. При вызове его из нескольких потоков, планировалось, что каждый поток получит свой массив состоящий из 2х строк. Но по факту в переменной **threadLocal** у каждого потока хранится массив из всех строк полученных каждым потоком.

**Вывод в консоль**

```
> Task :Main.main()
pool-1-thread-2 [pool-1-thread-2 : 0hinR1LDydRfYOZ9, pool-1-thread-1 : oK0wAEKHQh1WBiMv, pool-1-thread-2 : gAsXRkr3GoaloBdH]
pool-1-thread-1 [pool-1-thread-2 : 0hinR1LDydRfYOZ9, pool-1-thread-1 : oK0wAEKHQh1WBiMv, pool-1-thread-2 : gAsXRkr3GoaloBdH, pool-1-thread-1 : mb2Vdu9BAGoJlhpQ]
```

Comment: использование не-потокобезопасной переменной `array` в нескольких потоках без экранирования могло быть чревато. Чудо, что всё отрабатывает :)

Answer (score 0):

В общем разобрался. Нужно было инициализировать массив в каждом потоке и передавать его в качестве параметра в вызываемый метод

**Рабочий код**

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {

    private static final ThreadLocal<List> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private static final String AB = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private static SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    List<String> array = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
                    threadLocal.set(returnSomeList(Thread.currentThread().getName(), array));
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + threadLocal.get());
                }
            });
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    public static List<String> returnSomeList(String name, List<String> array) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(16);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
            }
            array.add(name + " : " + sb.toString());
            sb = new StringBuilder(16);
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```